# devstack openstack Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password

Tags: openstack

I have set up devstack on ubuntu 22 LTS using the following commands

```
echo “customUser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/customUser

git clone https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack
cd devstack
./stack.sh
cd ~/devstack/
source openrc
```

Loaded `admin-openrc.sh` from the GUI

```
$ env | grep OS
OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
OS_INTERFACE=public
OS_CACERT=
OS_AUTH_URL=http://192.168.192.110/identity
OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=default
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
OS_USERNAME=admin
OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION=3
OS_PROJECT_ID=bf9b26de572e4d53abf649fd6dda2c43
OS_AUTH_TYPE=password
OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
OS_PASSWORD=secret
OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

When I run the following command i seem to get error

```
$ sudo openstack quota set --secgroups 20 admin
Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using sudo in front of open stack which is not needed. without sudo it works